# How are field tables named?

Tags: entities, database

I am looking at my Drupal 7 database, and I think that I see the following pattern:

- Fields that are defined programmatically are stored in tables named field_data_fieldname
- Fields that are defined via the UI are named field_data_field_fieldname.

I don't find this convention documented anywhere. Did I take it right?

Answer (score 1):

- Any field created with the core Field UI module has its name prefixed with `field_`.
- Any field created programmatically is named exactly as the module creating it wishes, without the prefix.
- The field data tables are named directly from the field names

Yes, you have it absolutely right.

It's worth noting that the data is also stored in field_revision_foo, regardless of whether you're using revisions or not. The field_data_foo tables will always contain the most up-to-date data whether revisions are enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

The table name is always `field_data_<machine_name_of_the_field>`.

It just happens that the Field UI module adds *field_* as part of the machine name, which is derived from the field name entered in the UI. So, if you create a *Birthday* field, the Field UI module will use *field_birthday* as machine name of the field, and Drupal will use field_data_field_birthday as database table name.